# Does BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS guarantee compatibility to -fno-exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, boost

I want to use Boost.Filesystem together with `-fno-exceptions`. According to the [Boost.Filesystem documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) it states that it supports the `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` macro.

However, the following [snippet](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75e85c30ff187f6fv):

```
#define BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {}
```

compiled with:

> g++ -fno-exceptions boost_test.cpp

gives the error:

> /.../boost/filesystem/operations.hpp: In constructor
>   'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error::filesystem_error(const string&,
>   boost::system::error_code)':
>   /.../boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:84:16: error:
>   exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
>            catch (...) { m_imp_ptr.reset(); }

I compile using gcc 5 and boost version 1.57 on Mac OSX (also tested on similar ubuntu setups).

I am wondering whether my understanding of `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is right in that it should cover the usage of `-fno-exceptions` or whether it's simply there for the `boost::throw_exception` part?

Comment: Compiles for me with Clang 3.6, can reproduce with GCC 5.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, "no" is the obvious answer here, g++ cannot deal with the filesystem_error class.  There's a humdinger in boost/filesystem/config.hpp:

```
//  throw an exception  ----------------------------------------------------------------//
//
//  Exceptions were originally thrown via boost::throw_exception().
//  As throw_exception() became more complex, it caused user error reporting
//  to be harder to interpret, since the exception reported became much more complex.
//  The immediate fix was to throw directly, wrapped in a macro to make any later change
//  easier.

#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(EX) throw EX
```

This macro is used extensively in libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp to throw exceptions.  This is a show-stopper.

Fwiw, your sample program only *appears* to compile properly in clang and MSVC++, they only complain in their back-end about having to emit exception handling code, g++ does it in its front-end.  No complaint from clang/msvc++ for this sample code since that exception handling code was already emitted previously, back when the boost libraries were built.

Which demonstrates another severe problem with your approach, you probably originally built boost without -fno-exceptions in effect.  Not good.

Comment: A humdinger indeed, because BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW() and filesystem_error are in fact used extensively in boost::filesystem functions (in particular in operations.cpp).

Comment: Ah, yes, completely missed that one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) the documentation says:

> All exceptions thrown by the Filesystem Library are implemented by calling boost::throw_exception(). Thus exact behavior may differ depending on BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS at the time the filesystem source files are compiled.

In my understanding, it doesn't really say it support `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS`

And when I did a `egrep -r BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` under the filesystem directory, I found nothing

And after I read the source code, it supports my guessing. There are many places using `try { ... } catch(...)` in the code. You can also tell from the error message you got. Here is an example:

```
filesystem_error(
  const std::string & what_arg, const path& path1_arg,
  const path& path2_arg, system::error_code ec)
  : system::system_error(ec, what_arg)
{    
  try  
  {    
    m_imp_ptr.reset(new m_imp);
    m_imp_ptr->m_path1 = path1_arg;
    m_imp_ptr->m_path2 = path2_arg;
  }    
  catch (...) { m_imp_ptr.reset(); }
}
```

And if you read [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/exception/doc/configuration_macros.html), the semantic of `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is actually not disabling exceptions, but:

> forwarding all exceptions to a user-defined non-template version of
>   boost::throw_exception.

Comment: The fact that it promises to use `boost::throw_exception()` explicitly promises that it supports `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` (by using Boost Exception throughout). It makes sense that the implementation detail(s) are part of Boost Exception, not the Filesystem Library. All of this hardly addresses the question whether define `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` should make the code `-fno-exceptions` compatible.

Comment: @sehe, the thing is that, the code already uses `try {} catch(...)`, If should use BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS around the code in filesystem to support `-fno-exceptions`.

Comment: Recent versions (at least) of Boost use `BOOST_TRY`, `BOOST_CATCH`, etc, which expand to `try`, `catch`, etc when `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is not defined, but to `if (true)`, `else if (false)` etc when it is.